# How to keep the size of google chart columns and force scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-visualization

I have a google chart that will be generated via a database search to populate it. However, if this columns which in my case are companies are too many, it will keep shrinking the size of the column bars. See the image examples below.

Image 1 limit search to 10:

[image]

But if I add a lot more companies, that means not limit my search result this will happen:

[image]

Is there a way to limit the size of my colums to the one of the first image, and if it exceeds that to create a scroll bar?

I already have something like:

```
 #detailedCharts {
 overflow-x: scroll; 
 overflow-y: hidden;
 min-height: 500px;
 min-width: 100px;   
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

As CSS in hopes it would get to big and overflow so it would create a scroll bar on the div but this didnt work as expected.

The code I am using for the chart is as follows:

```
 static drawChartGetTotalIssuesByCategoryAllCompanies(data) {
        let dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        dataTable.addColumn("string", "Company Name");
        dataTable.addColumn("number", "Issue Count");

        data.forEach(row => { dataTable.addRow([row.name, row.issueCount]) });
        let chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("detailedCharts"));
        const options = {
            title: "Issues per Company for category",
            hAxis: {
                title: "Company Name"
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: "Issue Count"
            },
        };

        chart.draw(dataTable, options);
    }
}
```

The data I am passing in is an array of objects that look like this:

```
 public int IssueCount { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
```

And the html this chart will be placed in will be this:

```
<div class="row">
            <div id="detailedCharts" class="col-sm-12">
                
            </div>
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to assume the rest of your code, but there is potential solution. Maybe CSS is not the best option, because chart width is usually decided based on it's parent's width. I would add flexible width inside chart functionality:
First, get number of elements in a chart:

```
var numberOfElements = data.qg.length;
```

Then multiply them with the value you'd like:

```
  var newWidth = (numberOfElements * 100);
```

Then add this value to the `options` array, as a `width` parameter:

```
  var options = {
    width: newWidth
  };
```

If you have not enough elements, you can limit your width to be generated only when more than x elements. If less, it will keep default value. Example (to generate width only when more than 4 elements):

```
var newWidth =  (numberOfElements > 4) ? (numberOfElements * 100) : 0;
```

You can do the same for minimum width. Example (to generate width only if calculated width will be more than 400):

```
var newGeneratedWidth =  (newWidth > 400) ? newWidth : 0;
```

And then update your `width` value with the new `newGeneratedWidth:`

```
width: newGeneratedWidth,
```

Here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/e7de4e4h/

Comment: Hi thanks for this I will check it tommorow as I cant right now what else of code you would like to see to help understand the situation?

Comment: It would be nice to know your js (googleCharts) code, and maybe your HTML code. I suppose this should work anyway, but it would be nice to be able to test it.

Comment: Ok will test and add it tommorow if this doesn't work thanks

Comment: Hi again so i got a chance to test this today and this didnt work with this error 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: let me change that to the full code as i took the parts i considered would be usefull and not really sure how to do a code snipper as my data comes from a database, updated the js script to the whole for the chart

Comment: actually this is correct i just made a mistake when you provided the answer it appears to be modifying the size of the chart accordingly, thanks

Comment: I am glad it worked. I started going trough documentation again, because I thought there were some structural changes. Thanks for answering my questions

Comment: do you know if its possible to prevent it from becoming to small now hahah?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136451/discussion-between-armin-and-avaloth-oath).